# Why looping Tinydb.update work just for the first time in loop

Tags: python, arrays, foreach, nested-loops, tinydb

actual version of tinydb 4.3.0

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
db = TinyDB('db.json')
    dbtable = db.table('Counters')
    Search = Query()
    splitemsg = ['', 'nwm', '', 'nwm', '', 'nwm', ''] #in other cases it can be different
for tableval in dbtable.all():
    for i in splitemsg:
       if i == counterfilt:
          dbtable.update({'Value': tableval['Value'] + 1}, Search['Counter_filter'].any(counterfilt)) #this will add 1 to the Value in the table
```

my json file row:

> {"_default": {}, "Counters": {"1": {"Counter_name": "nwm",
> "Counter_filter": ["nwm", "nvm"], "Value": 0}}}

After this it is supposed to add 3 to the value in my table in tinydb, but it just add 1,
why it's not working?
I tried some sleep inside loop, didn't work.
I tried other versions of tinydb, didn't work.
I would have another solution for this if I can split the string, but separator is variable and I need the separator to be keeped.

Comment: Are you adding 1 here:`{'Value': tableval['Value'] + 1}`?

Comment: @DavidCollins yes, in the row is now zero